# Задача на полный перебор не прошла по времени C++

Tags: c++, рекурсия, олимпиада

Условие [задачи](https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=5&id_section=29&id_topic=137&id_problem=854):

> Даны N целых чисел X1, X2, …, XN. Требуется расставить между ними
> знаки «+» и «-» так, чтобы значение получившегося выражения было равно
> заданному целому S.
>
> **Входные данные** Входной файл INPUT.TXT в первой строке содержит числа N
> и S. В следующей строке располагается N чисел, разделенных пробелом.
> Ограничения: 2 ≤ N ≤ 24, 0 ≤ Xi ≤ 5*10^7, -10^9 ≤ S ≤ 10^9.
>
> **Выходные данные** В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите «No solution»,
> если такой результат получить невозможно, иначе выведите получившееся
> равенство. Если решение не единственное, выведите любое.

Ну первые мои мысли при данной задаче: N у нас достаточно маленькое, а значит вполне можно перебрать все возможные случаи расстановок знаков. Ну и методом "вдумчивого взгляда" можно понять, что жадный алгоритм тут придумать невозможно. Поэтому я реализовал полный перебор:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

string ans;

//функция генерации всех возможных сумм
void generate(const ll& need, ll sum_now, const vector<ll>& a, ll i, string str)
{
    if (i == a.size())
    {
        if (need == sum_now)
        {
            ans = str;
        }
    }
    if (i < a.size())
    {
        generate(need, sum_now + a[i], a, i + 1, str + "+" + to_string(a[i]));
        generate(need, sum_now - a[i], a, i + 1, str + "-" + to_string(a[i]));
    }
}

int main()
{
    ll n, s;
    cin >> n >> s;
    vector<ll> a(n);
    for (auto& x : a)
        cin >> x;
    
    //a[0] может быть только положительным, поэтому сразу вставляем его в сумму
    generate(s, a[0], a, 1, to_string(a[0])); 
    if (ans.empty())
        cout << "No solution" << endl;
    else
        cout << ans + "=" + to_string(s) << endl;
        
}
```

И данное решение не прошло по времени. И не совсем понятно почему. Всего вариантов перебора 2^23 < 10^7. По идее должно быть быстро. Встает два вопроса:

Можно ли как-то в случае нахождения верного ответа сказать программе завершить все вызовы рекурсий сразу и закончить работу функции? У меня конечно есть мысль, что можно написать return, но по факту мы же только 1 из вызывов завершаем? Будет ли завершать эта версия выполнять это:

```
void generate(const ll& need, ll sum_now, const vector<ll>& a, ll i, string str)
{
    if (i == a.size())
    {
        if (need == sum_now)
        {
            ans = str;
            return;
        }
    }
    if (i < a.size())
    {
        generate(need, sum_now + a[i], a, i + 1, str + "+" + to_string(a[i]));
        generate(need, sum_now - a[i], a, i + 1, str + "-" + to_string(a[i]));
    }
}
```

Естественно по идее данная оптимизация не сильно поможет, потому что самая долгая работа все равно будет в случае если должно вывестись "No solution" а значит перебор всех случаев неизбежен. Как можно оптимизировать мой алгоритм?

Встает вопрос, существует ли итеративное решение к данной задаче, а не рекурсивное? Просто мыслей к нему нет никаких, если дадите подсказки буду рад.

Код решения Harry, который тоже чуть чуть не прошел (см ответ Harry и комментарии к нему):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

int main()
{
    ll n, s;
    cin >> n >> s;
    vector<ll> a(n);
    for (auto& x : a)
        cin >> x;
    int M = 1 << (n - 1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        ll sum = a[0];
        int m = i;
        for (size_t j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (m & 1)
                sum += a[j];
            else
                sum -= a[j];
            m >>= 1;
        }
        if (sum == s)
        {
            cout << a[0];
            m = i;
            for (size_t j = 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (m & 1)
                    cout << "+" << a[j];
                else
                    cout << "-" << a[j];
                m >>= 1;
            }
            cout << "=" << s;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "No solution";
     
}
```

Comment: Я бы использовал схему Грея, и на каждом шаге перебора мне требовалась бы только одна(!) арифметическая операция, а не расчет всей суммы заново. Посмотрел внимательнее — а строки-то вам зачем?!!!! Ну вы даете...

Comment: @Harry вы имеете ввиду код Грея? (гугл на схему грея мне ничего не ответил) Я с ним еще в данный момент не знаком, но если он действительно может помочь, то я могу это дело изучить

Comment: @Harry ну строки использовал из за формата вывода. Мне же нужно вывести выражение полностью и с его знаками. Поэтому запоминать какой знак я присвоил каждому выражению я решил буквально строкой. Хотя действительно, я сейчас подумал, что у меня создается просто очень много ненужных строк. И это похоже действительно ключевой момент в медленной работе моей программы. Но как сделать иначе у меня пока, что мыслей нет, я немного подумаю

Comment: `как сделать иначе` в рамках минимального изменения вашего рекурсивного решения - передавать вместо строки 32-битовое число, устанавливая очередной  бит в 0 или 1. При нахождении решения расшифровываете эти биты в плюсы-минусы. Про Грея - да, код может быть полезен при итеративном решении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, полный перебор, даже без Грея...
По времени вполне укладывается. Просто не нужны никакие строки!

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> x;
    int N, S;
    cin >> N >> S;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int z;
        cin >> z;
        x.push_back(z);
    }
    unsigned int M = 1;
    M <<= N-1;
    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < M; ++k)
    {
        unsigned int m = k;
        int sum = x[0];
        for(int j = 1; j < N; ++j)
        {
            if (m&1) sum += x[j]; else sum -= x[j];
            m >>= 1;
        }
        if (sum == S)
        {
            m = k;
            cout << x[0];
            for(int j = 1; j < N; ++j)
            {
                if (m&1)
                {
                    cout << "+" << x[j];
                }
                else cout << "-" << x[j];
                m >>= 1;
            }
            cout << "=" << S << "\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "No solution\n";
}
```

P.S. Писано бегом, так что не оптимизировано и с определенными "затычками"...

Comment: Хотел спросить один момент, я сделал код как у вас, но при этом ввод в вектор оставил через range-based цикл. (код приложил к вопросу в конец) И это не прошло по времени. В то время как ваш код прошел по времени. А почему ваше решение вышло чуть быстрее? Разве наоборот не должно быть ваше быть более медленным? Ведь мы создаем пустой вектор, там могут быть потенциальные реаллокации (ну на самом деле на 24 элемента конечно я не уверен что они там будут, но ведь могут быть?). Я не совсем пойму причину более медленной работы моего кода. (по времени вышло буквально 0.53, а ограничение 0.5)

Comment: А что если у вас их нет? Поток закроется раньше времени. Похоже, обработка ошибок чтения из закрытого потока время съедает. Это так, первая версия, разбираться детально не тянет...

Comment: Скорее всего to_string схавал время, вместе с операциями со string.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Он же пишет о моем коде, просто чтение у него другое - `cin >> n >> s;
    vector<ll> a(n);
    for (auto& x : a)
        cin >> x;`

Answer (score 1):

Вы всё сделали правильно, кроме двух вещей: не надо было составлять строку для ответа в процессе поиска. Строковые операции сопряжены с выделением памяти и копированием её на каждом вызове.

Вторую неправильную вещь вы сами упомянули - нет нормальной остановки в момент когда решение найдено.

Код ниже обходит обе трудности, возвращая успех/не успех при поиске и печатая ответ кусочками в случае успеха:

```
#include <iostream>

int x[25];

bool search(int i, int s) {
    if (i == 0) {
        if (x[0] == s) {
            std::cout << x[0];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    if (search(i - 1, s - x[i])) {
        std::cout << '+' << x[i];
        return true;
    }
    if (search(i - 1, s + x[i])) {
        std::cout << '-' << x[i];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int n, s;
    std::cin >> n >> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> x[i];
    }
    if (search(n - 1, s)) {
        std::cout << "=" << s << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << "No solution\n";
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ time echo -e "24 24\n1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1" | ./a.out 
> 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=24
>
> real  0m0.002s
> user  0m0.000s
> sys   0m0.000s
>
> $ time echo -e "24 25\n1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1" | ./a.out 
> No solution
>
> real  0m0.055s
> user  0m0.052s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

P.S. В задаче сказано что `X_i` целые. Следовательно, там может быть ноль и отрицательные значения. Моя программа в этом случае печатает странное:

> ```
> $ echo -e "2 0\n-1 -1" | ./a.out 
> -1--1=0
>
> $ echo -e "2 -2\n-1 -1" | ./a.out 
> -1+-1=-2
> ```